# Default font size in default web browser of Ubuntu-Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, m10, webbrowser-app

How to increase default (QWebSettings::MinimumFontSize??) font size for 
web pages in WWW browser built in Ubuntu Touch? (for end-user)

Comment: Can't you just zoom in?

Comment: :) zooming is not suitable idea, because page content doesn't  fit in window in such case

Comment: won't changing the font size have the same problem

Comment: Hm, but I thought that this issue already has got a decision. But, I see now, it's not true.

Comment: should we move this to Stack Exchange chat?

Comment: you can make a new room here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=askubuntu.com

Comment: and you can start a room with me here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/234817/mark-yisri

Comment: @MarkYisri um, please don't do that. Targeted voting like what you just did is against the SE rules. In any case, there are automatic scripts that run every day that find and undo such votes.